# Replace Installed Apps with Snap

Tags: snap, snap-store

Is there a command to scan Ubuntu for all installed apps and replace them with their Snap version automatically?

Comment: Most users are trying to run away from snap apps. Why do you want more snap apps? Amongst other problems, apps are really slow to launch, and snaps increase boot times.

Comment: Ubuntu says they are the future so embrace it.  I do see several of mine were converted to Snap when I upgraded to Kubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Who said "snaps are the future"? Some applications are increasingly packaged as snaps because they are arguably easier for developers to create and maintain software but Ubuntu is not replacing all applications with snaps. If you're interested in a snap based ecosystem you can look at Ubuntu Core which relies heavily on snaps. See: https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-future-of-snapcraft

Comment: Ubuntu says it: https://ubuntu.com/blog/universal-snap-packages-launch-on-multiple-linux-distros

I plan to use the apps I use as Snaps if there is a Snap version.

Comment: I am not discouraging you from using snaps. Snaps are a very important part of the Ubuntu project and have helped to bring a larger volume and quality of applications to run on Ubuntu and other platforms. Ubuntu is great because there is such a wide variety of choice (just look how many flavours Ubuntu supports). The blog post I quoted you is the most recent official post that is literally titled "the future of snapcraft" - in response to your assertion that Ubuntu says that snaps are the future of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a command to replace all of your apps with snap applications.

However, you can use [snapcraft.io](https://snapcraft.io/) to search for snaps.

Then you can install whatever apps you want to use as snaps.  Most applications can be installed with:

```
sudo snap install appname
```

Replace `appname` with the name of the snap.  Review the application's page on snapcraft for more details.

To uninstall software in apt, you can use:

```
sudo apt remove packagename
```

Replace `packagename` with the name of the package.